# atan2 with CGPoint Iterator

Tags: c++, vector, iterator, atan2

```
vector<CGPoint>::iterator i;
vector<CGPoint>* bp = bicyclePad.bikePathPoints;
for(i = bp->begin(); i != bp->end()-3; i++){
    angle = atan2((*i).y/(*i).x) * 180/ PI;
}
```

I guess atan2 can only be used with floats and doubles. but I am trying to do it with an iterator. How would I go about doing the above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`atan2` takes two arguments:

```
angle = std::atan2(i->y, i->x) * 180 / PI;
```

should work fine. The correct overload (depending on what `CGFloat` typedefs to) will be chosen.

Note that `i->x` and `i->y` (which are strictly equivalent to `(*i).x` and `(*i).y`) are numbers (of type `CGFloat`), not iterators.

Comment: And I'll just note here that the reason it takes two arguments is that if `i->y` is nonzero, `i->x` is *allowed to be zero* even though that would nominally create a divide by zero error.

Comment: @MarkB: Also, `atan2(-1, -1) != atan2(1, 1)`. You get the full oriented angle of the vector `(x, y)` with `atan2`, and not just the inverse tangent of the quotient.

Answer (score 2):

This should work `atan2(i->y, i->x) * 180 / PI`